# How to make image scale without media css

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have this image name plate **(PAST CHAMPIONS)** for the plague and it looks decent on all screens except for iPhone portrait, it seems to get cut off.

Anyway to make this scale without media css?

Here is home page.
http://www51.myfantasyleague.com/2017/home/61106#0

Original code still in css

```
#championship_plaque h2 {
    background:
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)  
        url( "http://dagrafixdesigns.com/Images/2008/DA_2017/DA_Pro16/plaquetitle_glass.png" )
        no-repeat
        scroll
        center center
        !important;
    border: 0 none;
    margin-left: 25px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

Tried this code to no luck

```
#championship_plaque h2 {
    background:
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 
        url( "http://dagrafixdesigns.com/Images/2008/DA_2017/DA_Pro16/plaquetitle_glass.png" )
        no-repeat
        scroll
        center center
        !important;
    background-position: 70% 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Desktop:

[image]

Mobile:

[image]

I guess I can use media call to switch to a new image for this size screen if all else fails, just want to see if it can be done this way first.
thx

Comment: Is there a reason you're opposed to `@media()` queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example you're duplicating property values by using the shorthand `background` property with `!important` but then overriding them immediately afterwards. I recommend using the longhand properties when you want to be very clear about what's going on.

What you want is `background-size: contain` - which automatically *downscales* the image so it's 100% visible in the parent container. You also want to remove the `background-color: black`:

This is the rule I've got that works for me:

```
#championship_plaque h2 {
    background-image: url("http://dagrafixdesigns.com/Images/2008/DA_2017/DA_Pro16/plaquetitle_glass.png");
    background-size: contain;   
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Note that if you want to hide text there's a better approach than `text-indent: -9999px`, instead consider using this combination:

```
user-select: none;
color: #00000000; /* hex RRGGBBAA, AA=00 means 0% opacity, so the text is invisible */
```

Comment: Hey sorry about not posting photos bro...wont happen again.. So I got your code to work, and I can use media css but though has to be another way first. So we are good bro I thank you.   If you turn the iPhone to landscape, I have this rogue mini plague up higher than the rest, I cant duplicate on pc to fix, can you take a look please?  [link] (http://dagrafixdesigns.com/Images/2008/DA_2017/DA_RSkin/iphone.png)

Comment: @DA-G-GURU I suggest using CSS flexbox (`display: flex`) for that instead of `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: ok will look into that flex.....I think I will use media css now, as the contain is making the image blurry...sucks